# How to pass a List<String> as an argument of an object and display it in a textView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, textview

I try to develevop an android app, how can I pass a List as an argument f an object and display this List of participants in a TextView ?

```
private List<String> participants;



public Meeting(long id, String date, String hour, String place, String object, List<String> participants) {
    this.id = id;
    this.date = date;
    this.hour = hour;
    this.place = place;
    this.object = object;
    this.participants = participants;


public static List<Meeting> DUMMY_MEETINGS = Arrays.asList(
        new Meeting(1,
                "20/12/22",
                "14:00",
                "Salle A",
                " Dossier en attente","emre,sarah,robert"
        ));
```

I already passed previous arguments, my problem is just about the List.

Comment: Do you want to display only a single element from the list or you need to display every element in the list into your view

Comment: I  just want to know how to pass this list as an argument of Meeting and display only the list in  a textview, the other arguments are already displayed

Comment: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html Use the link above hope it will give you insight on what you are trying to complete

Comment: Thanks for responding